# Why does Seq give stack overflow when iterating through large csv file

Tags: f#, sequence, stack-overflow

I have a csv file with the following structure :

1. The first line is a header row
2. The remaining lines are data lines,
   each with the same number of commas, so we can think of the data in
   terms of columns

I have written a little script to go through each line of the file and return a sequence of tuples containing the column header and the length of the largest string of data in that column :

```
let getColumnInfo (fileName:string) =
    let delimiter = ','

    let readLinesIntoColumns (sr:StreamReader) = seq { 
        while not sr.EndOfStream do     
            yield sr.ReadLine().Split(delimiter) |> Seq.map (fun c -> c.Length )
    }

    use sr = new StreamReader(fileName)     
    let headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(delimiter) 
    let columnSizes =
        let initial = Seq.map ( fun h -> 0 ) headers
        let toMaxColLengths (accumulator:seq<int>) (line:seq<int>)  = 
             let chooseBigger a b = if a > b then a else b
             Seq.map2 chooseBigger accumulator line
        readLinesIntoColumns sr |> Seq.fold toMaxColLengths initial
    Seq.zip headers columnSizes;
```

This works fine on a small file. However when it trys to process a large file (> 75 Mb) it blows fsi with a StackOverflow exception. If I remove the line

```
Seq.map2 chooseBigger accumulator line
```

the program completes.

Now, my question is this : why is F# using up the stack? My understanding of sequences in F# is that the entire sequence is not held in memory, only the elements that are being processed. Therefore I expected that the lines that had already been processed would not remain on the stack. Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: How many rows and columns are there in the 75Mb file?

Comment: I don't know. At least 50,000. It's not so much that I want to get it to work, I am more curious as to why my understanding of F# was deficient. (although it would be nice to get it to work as well )

Comment: What happens if you do this: `Seq.map2 chooseBigger accumulator line |> Seq.toList |> seq`?

Comment: That does indeed fix the StackOverflow. I think you are correct about the laziness blowing the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a good question.  Here's a simpler repro:

```
let test n =
    [for i in 1 .. n -> Seq.empty]
    |> List.fold (Seq.map2 max) Seq.empty
    |> Seq.iter ignore
```

`test` creats a sequence of empty sequences, calculates the max by rows, and then iterates over the resulting (empty) sequence.  You'll find that with a high value of `n` this will cause a stack overflow, even though there aren't any values to iterate over at all!

It's a bit tricky to explain why, but here's a stab at it.  The problem is that as you fold over the sequences, `Seq.map2` is returning a new sequence which defers its work until it's enumerated.  Thus, when you try to iterate through the resulting sequence, you end up calling back into a chain of computations `n` layers deep.

As Daniel explains, you can escape this by evaluating the resulting sequence eagerly (e.g. by converting it to a list).

**EDIT**

Here's an attempt to further explain what's going wrong.  When you call `Seq.map2 max s1 s2`, neither `s1` nor `s2` is actually enumerated; you get a new sequence which, when enumerated, will enumerate both of them and compare the yielded values.  Thus, if we do something like the following:

```
let s0 = Seq.empty
let s1 = Seq.map2 max Seq.emtpy s0
let s2 = Seq.map2 max Seq.emtpy s1
let s3 = Seq.map2 max Seq.emtpy s2
let s4 = Seq.map2 max Seq.emtpy s3
let s5 = Seq.map2 max Seq.emtpy s4
...
```

Then the call to `Seq.map2` always returns immediately and uses constant stack space.  *However*, enumerating s5 requires enumerating s4, which requires enumerating s3, etc.  This means that enumerating s99999 will build up a huge call stack that looks sort of like:

```
...
(s99996's enumerator).MoveNext()
(s99997's enumerator).MoveNext()
(s99998's enumerator).MoveNext()
(s99999's enumerator).MoveNext()
```

and we'll get a stack overflow.

Comment: Apparently, my logic is wrong since this works for smaller files. I started going down the same path as you, but I don't see how it results in a stack overflow (out of memory, maybe).

Comment: @Daniel - I've tried to expand on my explanation.  Let me know if that clears it up.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains so many sequences it's hard to reason about. My guess is that's what's tripping you up. You can make this much simpler and efficient (eagerness is not all bad):

```
let getColumnInfo (fileName:string) =
  let delimiter = ','
  use sr = new StreamReader(fileName)
  match sr.ReadLine() with
  | null | "" -> Array.empty
  | hdr ->
    let cols = hdr.Split(delimiter)
    let counts = Array.zeroCreate cols.Length
    while not sr.EndOfStream do
      sr.ReadLine().Split(delimiter)
      |> Array.iteri (fun i fld ->
        counts.[i] <- max counts.[i] fld.Length)
    Array.zip cols counts
```

This assumes all lines are non-empty and have the same number of columns.

You can fix your function by changing this line to:

```
Seq.map2 chooseBigger accumulator line |> Seq.toList |> seq
```

Comment: It doesn't directly answer the question, is it?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but it points out the likely source of the problem (too much laziness). Taking a simpler approach will likely avoid hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: If I wanted someone to point out that laziness was the source of my problems I would have asked my wife  :-)

Comment: She'll probably tell you the same thing: eagerness is not all bad.

Comment: I don't get it. Although `state` is overwritten, `x` stays the same. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't think the logic in your update is correct when it comes to "zipping `line` with itself" (unless I'm misreading you).  This clearly doesn't cause an infinite loop, since the OP indicates that the function works for small files.

Answer (score 1):

> why is F# using up the stack? My understanding of sequences in F# is that the entire sequence is not held in memory, only the elements that are being processed. Therefore I expected that the lines that had already been processed would not remain on the stack. Where is my misunderstanding?

The lines themselves are not eating up your stack space. The problem is you've accidentally written a function that builds up a huge unevaluated computation (tree of thunks) that stack overflows when it is evaluated because it makes non-tail calls O(n) deep. This tends to happen whenever you build sequences from other sequences and don't force the evaluation of anything.